# Highcharts treemap slow rendering upon drilldown

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, highcharts

I have built a Highcharts treemap with quite a large data set. There are two levels in the hierarchy, with about 300 nodes at the top level and as many as 83 children of one of the top-level nodes. When I click on one of the top-level nodes, the treemap of the children nodes is very slow to render (~8 s). I am using Chrome, and I recorded this click function in the Timeline feature of Chrome Developer Tools. It turns out that the vast majority of the time spent rendering this image occurs in functions that Chrome labels "Recalculate Style" and "Layout". In each of the Layout functions, there is a warning "Forced synchronous layout is a possible performance bottleneck." Is there an easy way to batch these operations or otherwise reduce the number of calls of this type? I am finding that the resulting delay is making the chart prohibitively slow. Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Have you tried to disable animations / shadows ? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

Comment: I did try this. Looks like shadows are disabled for treemaps by default. I tried disabling animations as well, but to no avail... I have seen substantial performance improvements by disabling "enableMouseTracking" and/or "allowDrillToNode", but these are critical features that I would like to preserve.

Comment: Are you able to replicate your example as live demo ?